# Is it safe to remove lubuntu-desktop?

Tags: lubuntu, 14.10

I have re-installed Lubuntu 14.10 on my laptop (eee pc 701),but if I want to remove anything, he will also remove the package "lubuntu-desktop". Is it safe to remove?

Comment: No, what are you trying to remove and how are you doing it.

Comment: I'm trying to remove gnumeric, pidgin, sylpheed, transmission, mtpaint, xpad, audacious, gnome-mplayer, xfburn, guvcview, and many other things using sudo apt-get --purge autoremove <package-name>...

Comment: How are you doing this, Terminal ?

Comment: Yes, using the terminal

Comment: One at a time or as one long command

Comment: As one long command

Comment: Why do you want to know that???

Comment: OK, probably one of the packages you are trying to install is part of the desktop, Try one at a time like this - sudo apt-get purge "packagenamehere" - try a few and let me know what happens

Comment: More like, why do you want to remove all that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's safe to remove. It's a "metapackage":

> One of the handy features of apt (the packaging system used by Ubuntu)
>   is the use of metapackages. These packages do not contain actual
>   software, they simply depend on other packages to be installed. This
>   setup allows entire sets of software to be installed by selecting only
>   the appropriate metapackage. For example, an Ubuntu user can install
>   the Kubuntu environment (KDE and all its associated programs) by
>   selecting "kubuntu-desktop."

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages

Because one or more of the packages you are uninstalling are a dependency of the lubuntu-desktop package, it will need to be removed as well. But removing the lubuntu-desktop package itself won't break anything since it doesn't contain any actual software.

You can see more information about the package (such as which packages it depends on) by running this command in a terminal:

```
apt-cache show lubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: But, beware you aren't taking out any *other* components unintentionally - this particular one is OK,  but if you get a list of items to be removed don't assume they're all OK! There is value to removing a shorter list at a time if you're not sure.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. It's always good to look at what's being uninstalled, or you run the danger of ending up like this person: [apt-get -f install simply removed all the ubuntu packages and destroyed the system](http://askubuntu.com/q/606404/18665)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Lubuntu-desktop is a metapackage.  It can be safely removed if you want to remove some programs that are installed by default.